How to Minimize the Number of Digit 1s Needed to Represent a Number Using Sums and Subtractions?
I am trying to express a given integer $N$ using the minimum number of digit 1s. The integer should be represented as a sum and/or subtraction of numbers composed entirely of the digit 1 (e.g., 1, 11, 111, etc.). Each digit 1 used in the representation should be counted.
For example, the number 7 can be expressed as: 7 = 11 − 1 − 1 − 1 − 1. This uses 6 ones in total.
I’m looking for a mathematical function or strategy to minimize the number of digit 1s required for any given number $N$. What would be the best approach or algorithm to solve this problem?
Here is my code:
def digit_one(n):
    k = 1
    m = n
    while True:
        m //= 10
        k += 1
        if m == 0:
            break
    
    posibilities = []
    
    for i in range(1, k + 1):
        posibilities.append(int('1' * i))
        
    print(posibilities)

    l = 1
    acumulator = 0
    
    while n != 0:
        prev_n = n
        print(n)
        upper = abs(posibilities[len(posibilities) - l] - abs(n))
        lower = abs(abs(n) - posibilities[len(posibilities) - l - 1])
        
        if abs(n) in posibilities:
            for r in posibilities:
                if r == abs(n):
                    acumulator += len(str(r))
            break
            
        if upper < lower:
            print("Upper")
            n -= posibilities[len(posibilities) - l]
            acumulator += len(str(posibilities[len(posibilities) - l]))
        elif upper == lower:
            n -= posibilities[len(posibilities) - l - 1]
            acumulator += len(str(posibilities[len(posibilities) - l - 1]))
        else:
            print("Lower")
            if n < 0:
                n += posibilities[len(posibilities) - l - 1]
                acumulator += len(str(posibilities[len(posibilities) - l - 1]))
        
        if n == prev_n:
            l += 1
    
    return acumulator

print(digit_one(6090))

Problem comes with 6090. Must be 40 1s and find 41.

Not sure I'd expect there to be a nice description of that function.  I'd suggest:  write out the first dozen or so values of the function and search OEIS.  At least that might tell you if your sequence matches some other known sequence.

Worth noting, if $f(n)$ denotes your function then $f(n-1)-1≤f(n)≤f(n+1)+1$ so the sequence can't move more than $1$ at a time.  I think it might be interesting to describe those $n$ for which $f(n)=f(n+1)$.

Note:  if you allow multiplication, then we can represent $6$ using $5$ ones as  $6=(1+1)(1+1+1)$.   Without multiplication, the best you can do is $6$ as $6=1+1+1+1+1+1$.  Calling the "with multiplication",  sequence $F(n)$ this is A362626  I do not believe the "without multiplication" sequence is in OEIS but of course I might have miscomputed an entry or two.

11111-1111-1111-1111-1111-111-111-111-111-111-11-11=6090 (40 ones). I’ll try to provide general solution later today

Starting with 6090, you compute 11111-6090=5021 and 6090-1111=4979 ; 4979 is smaller than 5021, so you choose 4979 to continue your travel. The problem is that 4979 is difficult to reach, when 5021 is 4444+555+22, very simple to reach.

The function does not work for 6090, as stated. Worth noting that it does not work for smaller numbers too, e.g. for 63, it returns 19 (given by the unoptimized 111 - 11 - 11 - 11 - 11 + 11 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1), while f(63) should be 15 (11 + 11 + 11 + 11 + 11 + 11 - 1 - 1 - 1).

There are only 2 possibilities to reach the number $n$ :

from below:


from the largest number with repeated digits, ie. of the form $d \times \overline{11..1} \leqslant n$, with $d \in \{1, \dots, 9\}$.


from above which yields two subcases:


from the smallest number with repeated digits, also of the form $n \leqslant d \times \overline{11..1}$, with $d \in \{1, \dots, 9\}$,
or from the smallest number with repeated ones, of the form $n \leqslant \overline{11..1}$.

You can run the following code to compute the numbers:
def ones_abv(n):
    """Return the smallest '1'-only number >= n."""
    d = len(str(n))
    o = int('1' * d)
    if o >= n:
        return o
    return int('1' * (d + 1))

def sm_sgl_abv(n):
    """Return the smallest single-digit repeated number >= n."""
    d = len(str(n))
    for digit in range(1, 10):
        num = int(str(digit) * d)
        if num >= n:
            return num
    return int('1' * (d + 1))

def gr_sgl_blw(n):
    """Return the largest single-digit repeated number <= n."""
    d = len(str(n))
    for digit in range(9, 0, -1):
        num = int(str(digit) * d)
        if num <= n:
            return num
    return int('9' * (d - 1))

Now lets compute the values of $f(n)$ with Dynamic Programming :
min_dig = [0]  # DP array storing the minimum digit counts
n = 10000

for num in range(1, 1 + n):
    o = ones_abv(num)
    sm = sm_sgl_abv(num)
    gr = gr_sgl_blw(num)
    
    dig_sm = (sm % 10) * len(str(sm)) + min_dig[sm - num]
    dig_gr = (gr % 10) * len(str(gr)) + min_dig[num - gr]
    
    m_d = min(dig_sm, dig_gr)
    
    if o - num < num:
        dig_o = len(str(o)) + min_dig[o - num]
        m_d = min(m_d, dig_o)
    
    min_dig.append(m_d)

print(min_dig[6090])

>>> 40



I translated your Python code and wrote a program in VBA, which uses recursion. My program $\underline{\rm{does\space not}}$ calculate the minimum number of 1s of all the numbers from 1 up to the given number. This eliminates the use of array $\bf{min_dig}$ for storing minimum digit counts. However, I am unable to obtain from your algorithm any information about the individual counts of 1, 11, 111, 1111, etc., which are required to represent a given number using addition and subtraction. Is there a way to modify your program to calculate these counts?

@YNK Yes, I think that if you come from below, you use the + sign, with the correct number of ones needed, and if you come from above, you use the - sign.

Thanks a lot for the expanation
